# Is there a quick way to refresh Oracle table structure in Crystal Report

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports-2010

I have a CR using multiple Oracle tables with complex links. I have to change the structure of 1 table (add a field actually) but the new structure is not reflected in the crystal report. I have tried refresh or update the location but the newly added field could not be seen. I know there is a not so clever way to "solve" the problem is to delete the table and add it back but by doing that, I will have to recreate the link, rearrange the reports, recreate the calculated fields.... basically rewrite the whole report... any advice to help me quickly update the structure of the my ORACLE table would be highly appreciate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need to do is to Verify the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found that out ...accidentally. I updated the database location and refreshed it but the new schema was not updated. I decided to run the report anyway... At the time of the report execution, CR realized there was a change in the table structure and updated it! So I think the solution to this is updating the location then execute the report, CR will update it automatically. Do not need to delete the table and added it back because doing so will delete all the links and fields the tables was referring to.